# Using promtail and structured_metadata to reduce output but retain full data

Tags: promtail

In promtail there's an option to create structured_metadata in the pipeline.  I sort of want to take the original log message and store it into the map and then put it in structured metadata as `log` to represent the original log message.

Then I want to extract the `"message"` value and store that as an output.

I think the last bits of it would be

```
- json:
    expressions:
      message: message
- output:
    source: message
- structured_metadata:
    log:
```

But I am not sure how to do the first step which is to absorb the original line.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

```
      - regex:
          expression: (?P<log>.+)
```

So the whole thing is

```
- regex:
    expression: (?P<log>.+)
- json:
    expressions:
      message: message
- output:
    source: message
- structured_metadata:
    log:
```